# Prove a partial derivative change-of-variables identity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $u=f(x,y)$ where $x=e^{3s}\cos(2t)$ and $y=e^{3s}\sin(2t)$, then show that

$$ \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2= g(s,t)\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)^2 + h(s,t) \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right)^2$$

My attempt: I found $du/ds$ and $du/dt$, squared them, and added them. In the examples from class, something cancels out nicely but nothing did in this question. After some searching around, I found a [midterm solution](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~simic/Fall10/Math32/midterm2.10.soln.pdf) which is very similar to my question.

So far, I have $U_s^2 + U_t^2 = U_x^2(9x^2+4y^2)+10 U_s U_t xy+ U_y^2(9y^2+4x^2)$

Now I'm stuck because of the $9$ and $4$ in front of $x$ and $y$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SE! please try and use Latex next time, as well as add the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $u_s = u_x\cdot x_s+u_y\cdot y_s,\ u_t = u_x\cdot x_t+u_y\cdot y_t$:
$$u_s = 3e^{3s}(u_x\cos(2t)+u_y\sin(2t))$$
$$u_t = 2e^{3s}(u_y\cos(2t)-u_x\sin(2t))$$
Solve to get:
$$u_x =\frac{-2\cos(2t)u_s+3\sin(2t)u_t}{6e^{3s}}$$
$$u_y =\frac{2\sin(2t)u_s+3\cos(2t)u_t}{6e^{3s}}$$
Now add together $u_x^2$ and $u_y^2$ and see how all the the mixed terms ($\sim u_s u_t$) disappear.